# WinForm Design?

Tags: winforms

I'm coming from a web dev background, and do ok, but with WinForms, everything I make looks like crap.  Can you guys point me to resources with WinForm design principles that will make my WinForms easier on the eyes?

Thanks!

Comment: How do we know your web apps don't look like crap too?  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making WinForms look "Good" is a tall order. I have found it is best accomplished with a 3rd party package. Some the more popular...

http://www.devexpress.com/

http://www.infragistics.com/

http://www.telerik.com/

Of course, if you can move into the WPF you will have almost unlimited control on how you style the Ui elements....but, as pointed out by –nportelli, it will still look like crap out of the box.

Comment: The "look" problem does not evaporate.  Standard WPF controls are just as ugly as standard winform controls.  They are just easier to tailor to whatever look you want.

Comment: @nportelli You are absolutely correct..I shall rephrase.

Answer (score 4):

You should try windows presentation foundation instead.  That gives you the ability to build interfaces in a manner that's closer to the html you're familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have their own guidelines for Windows GUIs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511440.aspx

Answer (score 1):

YOu can also use http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/ or SliverLight, WPF